# PHP rename() directory on Windows for version 5.1.0

Tags: php

Function in question: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

The documentation says `5.3.1   rename() can now rename files across drives in Windows`. What it does not say is what the behavior is on older versions. I have searched for this in several places and I've seen people say that it does not move folders properly on Windows below 5.3.0, but I need to support 5.1.0+ (government system, they like to keep it old, and I need to support both Windows and Linux because clients use both).

Basically, what my code does is move a directory to its parent directory: `rename('some/dir/sub', 'some/dir')`. **I need to know if this will work on PHP 5.1.0 on both Windows and Linux.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to move between folders in the same drive, it will work regardless of the platform (if you have the right permissions).

If you need to move between different drives (ie. `rename("C:\\some\\folder", "D:\\another\\place");`, then you can try `rename` and use `copy` and `remove` as fallback:

```
$orig = "C:\\some\\folder";
$dest = "D:\\another\\place";

if (rename($orig, $dest) === false) {
    copy_recursive($orig, $dest);
    remove_recursive($orig);
}
```

In PHP there does not exist the `copy_recursive` or `remove_recursive` functions, but you can find multiples implementations in the net.

Comment: Alright, thanks :) I don't need to move between drives, and I hope I never will.

Comment: A side question about this: if I already have a folder at the destination path, does this function delete the contents of the destination directory or does it just overwrite matching files and keep the rest? I'm currently using a custom `recursive_rmdir` function to delete the destination folder if it exists.

Comment: @jurchiks I don't know what the behaviour is when the destination path already exists. According to [this comment](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php#60341) it will fail on windows if the destination exists.

Comment: Right, just another undocumented thing in the PHP universe.